# Is there a possibility to batch a select-query with SPARQL and RDF4J?

Tags: java, sparql, graphdb, linked-data, rdf4j

I am working with a quite large dataset (around 500Mio-Triples) stored in graphDB Free and running on my local developer machine.

I want to do some operations with the dataset with RDF4J and have to SELECT more or less the whole dataset. To do a test, I just SELECT the desired tuples. The code runs fine for the first Million tuples, after that it gets really slow since graphDB continues to allocate more RAM.

Is there the possibility to do a SELECT-Query on very big datasets and get them in batches ?

Basically I want just to "Iterate" trough some selected triples, so there should be no need to use that much RAM from graphDB. I can see that I allready get data in RDF4J before the query finishes, since it crashes (HeapSpaceError) only at about 1.4 Mio read tuples. Unfortunately somehow graphDB doesn't free the memory of the allready read tuples. Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot for your help.

ps. I allready set the usable heapSpace of graphDB to 20GB.

The RDF4J (Java) Code looks like following:

```
package ch.test;


import org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.*;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryConnection;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.http.HTTPRepository;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class RDF2RDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running RDF2RDF");

        HTTPRepository sourceRepo = new HTTPRepository("http://localhost:7200/repositories/datatraining");
        try {
            String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
            String sparqlCommand= Files.readString(Paths.get(path + "/src/main/resources/sparql/select.sparql"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

            int chunkSize = 10000;
            int positionInChunk = 0;
            long loadedTuples = 0;

            RepositoryConnection sourceConnection = sourceRepo.getConnection();
            TupleQuery query = sourceConnection.prepareTupleQuery(sparqlCommand);

            try (TupleQueryResult result = query.evaluate()) {
                for (BindingSet solution:result) {
                    loadedTuples++;
                    positionInChunk++;

                    if (positionInChunk >= chunkSize) {
                        System.out.println("Got " + loadedTuples + " Tuples");
                        positionInChunk = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

select.sparql:

```
PREFIX XXX_meta_schema: <http://schema.XXX.ch/meta/>
PREFIX XXX_post_schema: <http://schema.XXX.ch/post/>
PREFIX XXX_post_tech_schema: <http://schema.XXX.ch/post/tech/>

PREFIX XXX_geo_schema: <http://schema.XXX.ch/geo/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX XXX_raw_schema: <http://schema.XXX.ch/raw/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT * WHERE {

    BIND(<http://data.XXX.ch/raw/Table/XXX.csv> as ?table).

    ?row XXX_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?table.

    ?cellStreetAdress XXX_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;
        XXX_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://data.XXX.ch/raw/Column/Objektadresse>;
        rdf:value ?valueStreetAdress.

    ?cellOrt mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;
        XXX_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://XXX.mobi.ch/raw/Column/Ort>;
        rdf:value ?valueOrt.

    ?cellPlz mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;
        XXX_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://XXX.mobi.ch/raw/Column/PLZ>;
        rdf:value ?valuePLZ.

    BIND (URI(concat("http://data.XXX.ch/post/tech/Adress/", MD5(STR(?cellStreetAdress)))) as ?iri_tech_Adress).
}
```

**My Solution**:
Using a subselect statemant which gets all "rows" first.

```
PREFIX mobi_post_schema: <http://schema.mobi.ch/post/>
PREFIX mobi_post_tech_schema: <http://schema.mobi.ch/post/tech/>

PREFIX mobi_geo_schema: <http://schema.mobi.ch/geo/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX mobi_raw_schema: <http://schema.mobi.ch/raw/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT * WHERE {

    {
        SELECT ?row WHERE
        {
            BIND(<http://data.mobi.ch/raw/Table/Gebaeudeobjekte_August2020_ARA_Post.csv> as ?table).

            ?row mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?table.
        }
    }


    ?cellStreetAdress mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;
        mobi_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://data.mobi.ch/raw/Column/Objektadresse>;
        rdf:value ?valueStreetAdress.

    ?cellOrt mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;
        mobi_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://data.mobi.ch/raw/Column/Ort>;
        rdf:value ?valueOrt.

    ?cellPlz mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;
        mobi_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://data.mobi.ch/raw/Column/PLZ>;
        rdf:value ?valuePLZ.

    BIND (URI(concat("http://data.mobi.ch/post/tech/Adress/", MD5(STR(?cellStreetAdress)))) as ?iri_tech_Adress).
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you give GraphDB the memory. I mean, you load millions of tuples into your application, i.e. in-memory - so you should increase the Heap space of your Java application but not GraphDB.

Comment: The more important question, what does your application do with the data? What is your SPARQL query?

Comment: And indeed, you could also just get the result in chunks - just use `limit` and `offset``(and technically `order by`)

Comment: Question 1) 
I give graphDB the memory, because graphDB seems to need it. my java application doesn't need much RAM. So the heap space of the java application is not the problem. It's the heap space of graphDB which seems to be the problem.

Comment: Question 2) The application doesn't do anything at the moment. I will implement it, as soon as I get the data from the triplestore. The SPARQL query is just a SELECT-Statement to select some triples .

Comment: Question 3) Thanks for your tip with offset. I allready tried this, but it seems that graphDB is still allocating too much memory during the "Offset-Phase" before delivering the results.

Comment: what is the query? Indeed, a very complex query can be time and memory consuming. But it depends. And yes, pagination can be annoying - especially when you do it properly, i.e. with `order by` it can be too expensive because `order by` is more difficult than in SQL where you can just move the cursor

Comment: I added the query to the question. I don't really see, why it is so memory consuming for graphDB since i get the first tuples pretty quick. and after the "delivery", graphDB could free those memory ressources again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know immediately why the query given would be so costly, memory-wise, for GraphDB Free to execute, but generally a lot can depend on the shape and size of your dataset. Of course, doing a query that basically retrieves the entire database is not necessarily a wise thing to do in the first place.

Having said that, there's a couple of things you can try. Working with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` as a pagination mechanism is one way.

Another option you could try is to split your query in two: one query retrieves all identifiers of resources you're interested in, and then you iterate over those and for each do a *separate* query to get the details (attributes and relations) for that particular resource.

In your example, you could split on `?row`, so you'd first do a query to get all rows for the given table:

```
SELECT ?row WHERE {
    VALUES ?table { <http://data.XXX.ch/raw/Table/XXX.csv> }
    ?row XXX_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?table.
}
```

And then you iterate over that result, injecting each returned value for `?row` into the query that retrieves details:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    VALUES ?row { <http://data.XXX.ch/raw/Table/XXX.csv#row1> }

    ?cellStreetAdress XXX_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;
        XXX_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://data.XXX.ch/raw/Column/Objektadresse>;
        rdf:value ?valueStreetAdress.

    ?cellOrt mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;
        XXX_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://XXX.mobi.ch/raw/Column/Ort>;
        rdf:value ?valueOrt.

    ?cellPlz mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;
        XXX_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://XXX.mobi.ch/raw/Column/PLZ>;
        rdf:value ?valuePLZ.

    BIND (URI(concat("http://data.XXX.ch/post/tech/Adress/", MD5(STR(?cellStreetAdress)))) as ?iri_tech_Adress).
}
```

In Java code, something like this:

```java
String sparqlCommand1 = // the query for all rows of the table

// query for details of each row. Value of row will be injected via the API
String sparqlCommand2 = "SELECT * WHERE { \n"
                    + "    ?cellStreetAdress XXX_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;\n"
                    + "        XXX_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://data.XXX.ch/raw/Column/Objektadresse>;\n"
                    + "        rdf:value ?valueStreetAdress.\n"
                    + "    ?cellOrt mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;\n"
                    + "        XXX_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://XXX.mobi.ch/raw/Column/Ort>;\n"
                    + "        rdf:value ?valueOrt.\n"
                    + "    ?cellPlz mobi_raw_schema:isDefinedBy ?row;\n"
                    + "        XXX_raw_schema:ofColumn <http://XXX.mobi.ch/raw/Column/PLZ>;\n"
                    + "        rdf:value ?valuePLZ.\n"
                    + "    BIND (URI(concat(\"http://data.XXX.ch/post/tech/Adress/\", MD5(STR(?cellStreetAdress)))) as ?iri_tech_Adress).\n"
                    + "}";

try(RepositoryConnection sourceConnection = sourceRepo.getConnection()) {
     TupleQuery rowQuery = sourceConnection.prepareTupleQuery(sparqlCommand1);     
     TupleQuery detailsQuery = sourceConnection.prepareTupleQuery(sparqlCommand2);

     try (TupleQueryResult result = rowQuery.evaluate()) {
         for (BindingSet solution: result) {
                // inject the current row identifier
                detailsQuery.setBinding("row", solution.getValue("row"));

                // execute the details query for the row and do something with 
                // the result
                detailsQuery.evaluate().forEach(System.out::println);
         }
     }
}
```

You're doing more queries this way of course (N+1 where N is the number of rows), but each individual query result is only a small chunk, and probably easier for GraphDB Free (as well as your own application) to manage.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! that would be a nice and generic way to solve this problem. I know that querying a whole dataset is not really a good thing to do. but I have to do a transformation-like operation over all rows from an imported csv. 

I was able to reduce the ram-usage from graphDB with a subselect which gets all rows first. I added it to my original question.